# How to migrate data between Couchbase servers?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I'm new to Couchbase. Does anyone know **how to connect between Couchbase (CB) servers in order to migrate data**? I want to migrate data from a production CB server to my local server.

I found [here](http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/august/copying-documents-between-buckets-in-couchbase) how to migrate between buckets, but *within the same server*.

Also, I could do the migration between different servers using a backend application (I'm using C#.Net) using N1QL, but I want to learn how to do the server to server migration since it is a pretty standard and common operation .

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Ade Stringer who finally gave me the best solution, which is to use the [cbtransfer](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/cli/cbtransfer-tool.html) tool. This tool simply needs ***the source and target urls of the servers (and the names of the buckets)***, which is ideal since -- in general-- one doesn't have access to the  file system of the servers.

Here is a sample call:

```
cbtransfer http://10.10.10.68:8091 http://localhost:8091 -b SourceBucketName  --bucket-destination TargetBucketName
```

Note that the first parameter is the *source* CB server (http://10.10.10.68:8091) and the second one is the *target* CB server (http://localhost:8091). The value of the `-b` parameter is the name of the *source bucket*  and the value of the `--bucket-destination` parameter is the name of the *target bucket*.

In order to run this command in Windows, you must first go to the following folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin\
```

If one prefers to use the **`cbbackupmgr`** and **`cbbackup`** tools which were mentioned in the other answers, one needs to have access to the file system, which in my case was not possible. But still both tools are also useful nevertheless and I appreciate their answers.

Comment: The problem with cbtransfer is that it is an all or nothing event. If you were instead to use XDCR, it is a bit more intelligence built in. For example, with XDCR you can pause and restart and it'll pick up where it left off. It knows where it left off in the stream of changed data. There are others, but that is the easiest example. XDCR is simple to set up in the UI as well, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need continuous migration? Or backup/restore would be enough?

If latter, you can use `cbbackup`/`cbrestore` tools http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/backup-restore/backup-restore.html

Answer (score 2):

Either `cbbackup` and/or `cbrestore` or just turning on XDCR to get the changes from production to your local server would work too.

Definitely some security implications on doing this, but that's up to you to figure out! :)